# When you flag a post, can the 'Flag' button be highlighted or something?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags

I just flagged a post for the first time (spam), and clicked submit from the div popup.

But then I wasn't sure that the postback has been successful, as nothing happened on the main page. Could the flag button be highlighted or disabled to show that you have already flagged the question?

Comment: Also extend this to "close" and "delete" votes. I'm always trying to vote to close posts I've already voted on.

Comment: +1, I have this problem with flags and close votes too. (Not with deletions, because I haven't hit 10K. Hard to gain rep when all you do is edit and close!)

Comment: Hrm, I was about to vote to close this as a dupe of [Could the close/delete/flag buttons indicate whether or not we've already added that input to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73925/could-the-close-delete-flag-buttons-indicate-whether-or-not-weve-already-added), but then I noticed that this has a status tag.

Answer (score 4):

If you attempt to "flag" on a question/answer you have already flagged, you will be informed that you have already flagged such question/answer.

But, that is not to say the process could be improved some how. I have a feeling Jeff would decline this feature request, but he always continues to surprise us.

Comment: Still, the OP's proposal would be more intuitive. +1'd it

Comment: So why didn't you leave a comment instead of an answer then?

Answer (score 1):

This would require many, many queries per page load per logged on users.

Comment: The requested feature seems to be implemented for comments: When I hover over a comment I had flagged before, the flag (and vote up) icons are not show, so I know I have already flagged it. Aren't there more comments that questions?