# Notification after flagging a post?

Tags: feature-request, flags

When I've flagged a post, the corresponding pop-up just seems to disappear and I'm not sure if the flag was successful or not. It's very confusing. I see [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37147/when-you-flag-a-post-can-the-flag-button-be-highlighted-or-something), which seems to have high reviews, but little feedback. I don't understand why it isn't requested more frequently; the current system is very counter-intuitive and leaves me wondering.

Any form of display that my flag went through successfully would be extremely useful. The link I provided is actually a very good suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a notification box that appears if your flag *doesn't* go through successfully, it looks like this:

> ### An error has occurred - please retry your request
>
> #### (click on this box to dismiss)

It's probably safe to say that, if this box doesn't appear, your flag was successful.

If you flag posts via the moderation tools pages, you can go back there after flagging a post to see if the number of flags increased or refresh to see if the post has been deleted by Community.

I do think it's a little weird not having visual feedback.  It would be nice if, when clicking the flag link a second time, it looked more like the vote to close popup, taking away the radio inputs and showing you how many flags the post has received so far.  Maybe only for users with access to the moderation tools though.

Comment: Yes, some visual feedback would be nice. If I come back to a post I've forgotten I've flagged, there's nothing to remind me that I've actually flagged it. If I click it, it will say that I'd already flagged the post. Steps should be taken to prevent this from happening in the first place.