# Indicate that I already flagged in flagging dialog

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, flags

As Jeff said in  *[an answer to "When you flag a post, can the ‘Flag’ button be highlighted or something?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37147/when-you-flag-a-post-can-the-flag-button-be-highlighted-or-something/60019#60019)*, a realtime online indication whether I already flagged is too expensive.

How about doing the query after I click on flag, before showing me the flagging dialog? If I already flagged this item it will show me a dialog telling me that.

I assume most clicks on the flag link is followed by a submit, which will trigger the query anyway. Doing the query after click on flag, before showing the dialog, will not raise the amount of queries by much, but make many users happy.

Comment: I realize that this is the older question, but the newer one has more detail and discussion.