# Could the close/delete/flag buttons indicate whether or not we've already added that input to a post?

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

For the close/unclose/delete/flag functions, could we have some indicator (like we do for voting) that we've already marked a question? For example, to find out if I flagged a post already I have to hit the "flag" link again, and then be told by an error message that I've already flagged it. I'd rather that the "flag" link be modified after I've flagged the post, so that I don't have to click it again to find out. The same applies for the vote buttons for closing, un-closing, and deleting. I've had several times where I'd wander away from a particular SE site for a few days and come back, then wonder "Did I already mark that one?".  Currently, the only way to find out seems to be by attempting to perform the function again.

Comment: Do you mean other than when you actually click on them?

Comment: @Alejandro - I believe you understand correctly.  For example, to find out if I flagged a post already I have to hit the "flag" link again, and then be told by an error message that I've already flagged it.  I'd rather that the "flag" link be modified after I've flagged the post, so that I don't have to click it again to find out.  The same applies for the vote buttons for closing, un-closing, and deleting.