# Show the posts one has flagged in the user profile

Tags: discussion, flags

Today I flagged an empty post for moderator attention. About ten minutes later, I wanted to go back to check if there was something in it I had overlooked (the post appeared to be completely empty, which is something I thought impossible). I thought, easy, it'll show up in my profile. But it didn't. And now I can't even find that post anymore to provide a link to it in this question (maybe it has already been deleted by the moderators).

I did see the answer to this question:

[When you flag a post, can the 'Flag' button be highlighted or something?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37147/when-you-flag-a-post-can-the-flag-button-be-highlighted-or-something/60019#60019)

Which is something that I'd consider helpful, but apparently it strains the system too much. So, how about showing it on the user profile under "activity"?

Comment: For suggested edits, I reckon this has already been suggested. However, if it hasn't, you're free to suggest it, but I recommend **doing it in a separate post**. As it stands, it's kinda muddying this request by making it cover too much at once.

Comment: @Takri: sometimes posts can appear empty, even though they're not because the OP has posted XML.  If you're not sure, then you can check by clicking to edit the post (even if you discard it), that way you can see the raw content.

Comment: @forsvarir Thanks. It turns out that this actually was the case. I had wanted to go back to that post and check if there was some html in there that rendered the content invisible for some reason. Since I wasn't able to find it anymore, I posted this question. Someone else edited that post in question in the meantime. Anyhow, two lessons learned on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flags are private. We don't reveal who has flagged what, except to the original flagger and the moderators who read those flags. To that end, placing it in the "activity" tab is unwise, as that is meant to be a public location.

For most cases, you can find the flags you have cast by clicking on the flag weight that is displayed underneath your gravatar in your profile. Only you (and moderators) can do this. However, *this flag weight is only shown when you are not at the default 100 flag weight*. In this scenario, since this is your first flag, there is no flag weight shown.

As such, you'll need to visit the specific URL. This is at `/users/flag-weight/<userid>` for the appropriate site, where `<userid>` is your ID number. In your case for Stack Overflow, the address would be `http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/520044`. Remember, only you and moderators can visit this link, so the fact I'm posting it visibly here doesn't reveal anything to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

For someone who has more or less that the initial 100 flag weight you'll get a link in your profile (under your gravatar image) that you can click on.

Or you can visit the link directly:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/520044