# Show flag activity in profile even before flags processed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, profile-page, flag-history

When a regular user flags something it disappears into the system until the flag is processed by someone.

This is OK for active sites, but for less active sites, or sites like Meta where only employees handle flags and so processing can be slow on weekends/holidays, one can lose track of one's flags, and can't be sure what flags have actually been raised and are pending.  (E.g., on [one particularly inactive site](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) I'm pretty sure I raised a flag over a week ago, but nothing shows processed so how can I tell?)

Feature Request: Show all flags in [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223601/241697) immediately, initially marked as "unprocessed".

Related: [Show the posts one has flagged in the user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95904/show-the-posts-one-has-flagged-in-the-user-profile)

Comment: Um, they *do* show up immediately.  If they haven't been handled they show as "active".

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Not for us mere mortals.  Are you referring to a moderator view?

Comment: @feetwet no, I check this on sites where I'm not a moderator.  But have you perhaps never had a flag accepted?  Once you've had a flag accepted you'll see a "helpful flags" count on your profile and you can click that to see *all* your flags (with status).  Until you have that, you can manually construct the URL: (site)/users/flag-summary/(user#) .  (Only you and mods can see that page.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I just did a test of this, and yes I can see that now.  Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I just flagged this question for closure as "off-topic" due to the sub-reason "can no longer be reproduced."  But my flag queue only lists the flag as "off-topic," which is confusing.  But I guess I've entered enough feature requests for one day....